# How to save a table(DataTable) into a single cell in a database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, datatable

Is it possible to save a DataTable into SQL database in one cell of type binary for example and read it back again into a DataTable?

Comment: @Ahmad - In your comment to codemonkey4hire, What is meant by some answers may require a table? You mean that there is a many to one relationship between some answers and their questions? Are you able to post some details on your database design as we may be able to help you with that. Generally speaking, I'd be inclined to avoid having data in a database in a non-queryable format unless necessary e.g. ASP.NET Session State, documents uploaded by user, etc.

Comment: Table:(QuestionTables)
Columns:(ID, QuestionID, DataOfTable)

I don't need to query through those saved tables, I will only display them all as a whole block or delete them. Even no need to modify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would create, if possible, a xml field inside the sql database and save the datatable as xml

[XML Support in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx)

and

[C# and Vb.net example for XML data type tips in SQL Server 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/XMLdDataType.aspx)

should help you

another example took from [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/SQL-Server-2005/Q_22831189.html)

```
   protected bool LoadXml(SqlConnection cn, XmlDocument doc)
   {
    //Reading the xml from the database
    string sql =  @"SELECT Id, XmlField  FROM TABLE_WITH_XML_FIELD WHERE Id = @Id";
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
    cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id",1));
    using (SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
    {
             if (dr.Read())
            {
                      SqlXml MyXml= dr.GetSqlXml(dr.GetOrdinal("XmlField"));
                      doc.LoadXml( MyXml.Value);
                      return true;
            }
            else
            {
                      return false;
            }
     }
    }
```

Comment: +1 exactly - XML serialize the DataTable into an XML field and read it back from there, when needed

Comment: So I save it into an XML field in SQL? Can you please show me how to write the code that do that because I never dealt with this data type?

Comment: which sql server version you got?

Comment: Thanks dude, that's what I was looking for. But do you know how to transfer the XmlDocument to and from DataTable?

Answer (score 2):

why on earth would you want to?

If this is an operation you are going to do more than once, just save it out to a new sql table and read from the table into your DataTable later.

Comment: I am creating a system of questions and answers and some answers may require a table.

Answer (score 0):

It just breaks normalization rules- the value in the cell is not atomic.

I break that rule myself all the time, but still, it's important to understand alternative approaches.

You could have a related table to store their answers instead of storing all their answer values in a single cell.

Regarding your comment below, you can still do it with a related table.  Just use a three-column table: tableID, fieldID, value.  Each tableID can have its own set of fieldIDs.  The trade-off is with the value datatype- it needs to be a string, which means you don't get the advantages of date or numeric data type enforcement on your back end.

Comment: yeah but I will have many tables with different structures each time